# XMPP requests testing tool like Postman

Tags: xmpp

I would like to play around XMPP to learn and test some RFCs. But writing app to test them is just something I want ro avoid because of limited time.

For rest APIs Postman and the like have been time savers. So the question is, is there anything similar or at least closer that I can use to send XMPP requests and receive responses?

Comment: you can find some XMPP console, which allows you to send stanzas...

Comment: XMPP JS (https://github.com/xmppjs/console) or PSI (Qt, C++ ) client (https://github.com/psi-im/psi), allows to send raw XMPP stanzas...

Comment: Thank you. I will test them and let you know. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Psi+ (used latest dev build) have exactly what I was finding in terms of console. If you will post your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSI+ (Qt, C++ ) client (github.com/psi-im/psi), allows to send raw XMPP stanzas...

XMPP JS (github.com/xmppjs/console) might offer similar functionality